# How do I get Powershell to output Get-ADUser -Filter * as comma delimited?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a simple Powershell script that I want to use to grab all the users in AD and show specific properties.  Here is the heart of my script:

```
$id = "*"
Get-ADUser -Filter {SAMAccountName -like $id} -Properties * | Select-Object -Property SAMAccountName,Name,PasswordNeverExpires,LockedOut,PasswordLastSet,LastLogOnDate,CanonicalName
```

The full script has an input parameter to set $id so that it can be a single ID, a list of IDs (such as "bsmith, jdoe, gmanning"), or * to get all accounts.

**Here's my problem:** When using, *, I need this to output as comma delimited.

**Here's the catch:**  The output cannot be to a CSV file--or any other type of file.

The reason being is that I'm writing this script to be used on N-Enable's N-Central monitoring suite of software.  You don't need to know N-Central to help with my problem, just understand that N-Central uses its own software to run Powershell scripts on clients and returns the results into a txt file that cannot be changed to a csv file (or formatted in any other way than what it has hard-coded).

What this means is that my results have to either be what would show up on the screen or in a variable (such as $results=Get-ADUser -Filter * ....).  I cannot output to any type of file, which leaves out Export-CSV as an option.

I've tried other types of formatting to no avail  (such as with -f).  The issue seems to be with the way Powershell grabs all AD Users using the * wildcard.  It seems to grab them all as one big object, so I am unable to get my output to have a comma between all the properties so that I get a comma-delimited output. Thus, when I get the results back from N-Central as a .txt file, all the data is there, but there are no commas in between the properties for me to then open the .txt file as comma-delimited in Excel (or tab-delimited for that matter).

Does anyone have a solution that will allow me to format Get-ADUser -filter * so that it is comma-delimited without using export to file?

**UPDATE:** Ok, I thought I was keeping things easy by not posting my full script but it seems I've done the opposite. So, below is my full script.  Anyone should be able to run this to see the results:

```
function Get-ADUserInfo
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        #[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string[]]$Users= '*'

    )
    Begin {

        $maxPasswordAge = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge.Days
        $Headers="ID, Name, Password Never Expires?, Locked Out, Password Last Set, Expiry Date, Last Logon Date, OU Path"

    }
    Process {
        foreach ($id in $Users)
        {
            $results=Get-ADUser -Filter {SAMAccountName -like $id} -Properties * | select -property SAMAccountName,Name, PasswordNeverExpires,LockedOut,PasswordLastSet,(@{Expression={$_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays($maxPasswordAge)}}), LastLogOnDate,CanonicalName  | `
        ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation 

        }

    }
    End {
        $Headers
        $results
        }
}

Get-ADUserInfo -Users
```

Some notes:

1. When calling Get-AdUserInfo -Users, the script needs to work by entering a single ID, *, or multiple IDs separated by a comma when using the -Users parameter.
2. Using ConvertTo-CSV solved my biggest problem, comma separated output,thanks all.
3. I'd like to get rid of the headers that are auto-created as well ("SAMAccountName","Name","PasswordNeverExpires","LockedOut","PasswordLastSet","$_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays($maxPasswordAge)","LastLogOnDate","CanonicalName"). How can I do that?  I've tried -skip 1 but that doesn't work with * and removes everything (including the data) if used with a single ID or IDs separated with commas.  I can't get -ExpandProperty to work either. Adding format-table -hidetableheaders at the end doesn't do anything as well

Comment: Pipe it to `ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation`?

Comment: It's not clear what your output is supposed to look like.

Comment: Don't do `-Properties *`, you're being mean to the DSA

Comment: I'm not going to murder my AD servers and run  a `get-aduser -Filter *` query, but what exactly does it return if not an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you could use something like this then

```powershell
$props = "SAMAccountName","Name","PasswordNeverExpires","LockedOut","PasswordLastSet","LastLogOnDate","CanonicalName"
$results = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $props | Select $props | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This uses the `$props` array to make the actual query readable and enforce property order. Most of those properties are returned by default, like `samaccountname`, so it is not required to specify them but no harm done.

`$results` would contain a quoted comma delimited output. If the quotes bother you they should be removed with a simple `-replace`

```powershell
$results = $results -replace '"'
```

**Aside**

As others have mentioned you are wasting time using `-Properties *` you should only return the properties that you need. Which is, again, why I used `$props`.

**Update from comments**

If you want to remove the header column you just need to `-Skip` that from the output. At the end of the code that populates results just add `Select-Object`

```powershell
$results = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $props | Select $props | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1
```

Also to cover your calculated property the easiest way that I have found so far is to add another `Select-Object`. Not the way I would want to but for now it works.

```powershell
$results = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $props | 
    Select $props | Select-Object *,@{L="pWD";Expression={$_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays($masPasswordAge)}} | 
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1
```

## Game Changer

So you made some pretty big changes to your example by including your function. Try this on for size now.

```powershell
function Get-ADUserInfo
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        #[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string[]]$Users= '*'

    )
    Begin{
        $results = @()
        $maxPasswordAge = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge.Days
        $Headers= @{Label="ID";Expression={$_.SAMAccountName}},
        @{Label="Name";Expression={$_.Name}},
        @{Label="Password Never Expires?";Expression={$_.PasswordNeverExpires}},
        @{Label="Locked Out";Expression={$_.LockedOut}},
        @{Label="Password Last Set";Expression={$_.PasswordLastSet}},
        @{Label="Expiry Date";Expression={$_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays($maxPasswordAge)}},
        @{Label="Last Logon Date";Expression={$_.LastLogOnDate}},
        @{Label="OU Path";Expression={$_.CanonicalName}}

    }
    Process{
        foreach ($id in $Users){
            $results += Get-ADUser -Filter {SAMAccountName -like $id} -Properties PasswordNeverExpires,LockedOut,PasswordLastSet,LastLogOnDate,CanonicalName | select $Headers 
        }
    }
    End{
        $results | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation
    }
}

Get-ADUserInfo -Users
```

`$Headers=` contains a collection of calculate properties most of which are there the change the header. It does not need to be done this was and you could have just manually added a header line before the output of contents. This solution however is more in line with what PowerShell is capable of.

We collect all of the users in the array `$results` and in the `End` block convert that to CSV output which would not contain your custom headers.

Comment: Hey, thanks to everyone that answered my question.  Convertto-CSV did indeed work Don't know why I didn't think of that!  I know a lot of you mentioned not using -Properties * and Select-Object at the same time.  However, this was the only way I could get the script to run without an error.  One thing I didn't show in my original code was that I also  had a property, @{Expression={$_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays($masPasswordAge)}}, in there as well.  I didn't show it as I didn't want to add more than necessary so as not to confuse things too much.  I'll try Matt's $props idea, that shold work.

Comment: @DavidT Glad to here you found a solution. If one of these answers helped please considered marking your question as answered using the green check mark on the left.

Comment: Anyway to continue, ConvertTo-CSV worked but not -NoTypeInformation.  I'm still getting the column headers (SAMAccountName, etc) with the output which I do not want.  Anyway to get rid of that?  I tried adding Format-Table -HideTableHeaders but that didn't work either.

Comment: `-NoTypeInformation` is not for the header but it removes type information from the output. See my update.

Comment: I updated my original Q with my full code for the script as I think I wasn't being as clear as I thought by leaving some out.  The script needs to work with the input -Users parameter being either a single ID, multiple IDs (separated by commas), or * to denote all IDs.  I know there are probably better ways than using -Properties * and Select -Property together but this is the only way I've been able to make the script work.  Right now, though, I'm only interested in getting the headers removed from the output.

Comment: @DavidT look now and let me know if this works better.

Comment: Matt, that ALMOST works great.  It passes 2 of my 3 requirements.  It works when entering a single ID and with *, but fails (sorta) with multiple IDs.  So, for example, if I have "Get-AdUserInfo -Users user1, user2, user3", the script runs but I get the headers multiple times--once for each userID inputted.    Also, just for my Powershell learning benefit, what is the purpose of "@()" in "$results = @()" ? I haven't come across that before, what does it do?

Comment: @DavidT Oops. that was a silly mistake... just a moment. It's fixed now. Needed to move the convert into the `End` block. Also `$results = @()` sets the type to array to ensure the output will come out the same regardless of the amount of id's specified. PowerShell performs operations based on what is on the left hand side and we want to be sure that `+=` adds and array element and not some other action. Restart your PowerShell session and remove it and see what could happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = "*"
$userlist = Get-ADUser -Filter {SAMAccountName -like $id} -Properties  SAMAccountName,Name,PasswordNeverExpires,LockedOut,PasswordLastSet,LastLogOnDate,CanonicalName | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation
```

$userlist will be an array of users stored in CSV formatted lines

Edit: Combined -Properties * | Select [propertylist] and get rid of the pull of all properties.

Edit: included -NoTypeInformation so that the output is pure CSV.

Note:  Something should be done about the filter.

Comment: `SAMAccountName -like *` is worse than `-Filter *` because it has to read the SAMAccountName of each object and compare it to *.  If you use either your script will be an enormous resource hog.  Use a legit filter.  `Enabled -eq $True` or something.

Comment: Actually, [the sAMAccountName attribute is indexed by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc220838.aspx) (see `searchFlags`), the DC should be able to satisfy the query from the index alone

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen For each item the script pulls, it still has to compare to the filter.  Unfiltered pull skips the comparison, but still pulls all user objects.  He needs a filter that strips out unneeded entries, if possible.  Not sure what he's pulling the list for, but it sounds like this bit of automation could be used on a regular basis.  If it's more often than every few minutes, the load could be detrimental to performance of the AD servers.